# XML Find match in file and print it along with second value

Tags: python, xml, parsing

so I have this XML file:

```
 <langs>
      <lang "1">
        <name>Python</name>
        <text>Lorem ipsum</text>
      </lang>
      <lang "2">
        <name>C++</name>
        <text>Dolor sit amet</text>
      <lang "3">
        <name>C</name>
        <text>Consectetur adipiscing elit</text>
      </lang>
    </langs>
```

I need a function that finds a match in the file and displays it along with some other value, or to put it simply something like this:

```
result = find(xml, 'Pytho')
print(result)

>>> Python - Lorem ipsum
```

How do I do it?

Comment: The xml you have provided doesn't look valid. The lang node declares an attribute value without an attribute name. The second node isn't closed. Are you going to be parsing malformed xml documents like in your example? If so, you may want to check the beautifulsoup library.

Comment: Are you searching the text in the name node only or also the text node?